# Hockey Players Introduced After a Game

Tags: ice-hockey

At a [NAHL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAHL) game, I noticed as I was leaving that a few players, one by one, were being introduced back onto the ice after the game to have (what I describe as) a victory lap. I didn't pay attention to why this was happening.

Why are hockey players introduced after a game? Is this a common occurence in ice hockey?

Comment: There was no announcement: "And now, the three stars of the game.." ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually after a hockey game, a third party names the "Three Stars" of the game. This is based on the player's performance during the hockey game. These "Stars" come out one at a time and acknowledge the fans by either taking a lap or just raising their stick.

After a little digging, I found that in the NHL, the three stars was first awarded in the 1936–37 NHL season and continues today.

> Three stars are generally not awarded during international play, such
>   as at the Winter Olympic Games. The IIHF World Championships and World
>   Junior Championships instead issue awards such as "Best Player" for
>   each team per game, or the overall best player per position over the
>   course of the tournament.

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_stars_%28ice_hockey%29)

Comment: Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_stars_%28ice_hockey%29