# Which player was named the first star in most NHL matches?

Tags: trivia, ice-hockey, records, nhl

After a match in NHL (both in regular season and in Stanley Cup) three players are named [three stars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three_stars_%28ice_hockey%29) of the game. See also: [Hockey Players Introduced After a Game](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/1978/hockey-players-introduced-after-a-game/)

> What is the record for number of occasions a player was named the first star during one season? Which player got this honor most times throughout his career?

Comment: It's not a stat that can be found. I would say Wayne Gretzky has it for sure. Can't tell if they we're doing it back then. These days, it's probably Carey Price.

Comment: @Steve Still if  you are aware at least of some link where we could find which player from some club was awarded the first start most times, it would be first step towards an answer. (And maybe we could make a CW answer listing at least players for those clubs where this information is available.) I have not found something similar. (I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Philadelphia_Flyers_award_winners#Toyota_Cup) for Philadelphia Flyers, but it is not exactly what I ask in the original question.)

Comment: @milk2go they started the 3 stars in the 1936-1937 season,

Comment: Here is a limited chart of the 3 stars from 2009 to the current season: https://www.sportingcharts.com/nhl/stats/first-second-third-star-statistics/2016/. You can sort by the 1st, 2nd, or 3rd star, but the defualt is

Answer (score 2):

The NHL tracks which players have the most 1st stars then gives them points based on their accumulation of 1st 2nd and 3rd stars, where 1st --> 30 points, 2nd --> 20 points, and 3rd --> 10 points. This information can be found [here](http://www.nhl.com/ice/threestarsstandings).

Comment: The link you given is certainly interesting in connection to the question. However, it is three star points ranking for *current season*. Do you happen to know whether there is an archive of results from past seasons? Or - even better - cumulative ranking combining all seasons for which the stats are kept?